# install app only in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I develop universal app for windows phone
I want to prevent install app in windows phone 8.0 I want just install in windows phone 8.1
how can do this in manifest ?
I try add capability but its still install in windows phone 8.0

Here is what has been tried so far:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" /> <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" /> </Capabilities>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried?

Comment: <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
            <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
        </Capabilities>

Comment: can you please share, on what windows phone o/s version you, actually used to build the your application?

Answer (score 0):

In yout WMAppManifest.xaml change the AppPlatformVersion attribute in Deployment tag like this:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2014/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.1">
```

Comment: i try it Error 1 AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml Harmonie.WindowsPhone.App

Comment: Error 3 AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml Harmonie.WindowsPhone.App

Comment: Try double clicking project Properties and update the combo value for "Target Windows Phone OS Version". It should update the project AND the manifest.

Comment: i want to still use sdk 8.0

Comment: i want to still use SDK 8.0 , but i still want the app enable install in windows 8.1 and prevent install and block it in windows phone 8.0 how can I achieve this?

Comment: That makes no sense to me, all functionality of 8.0 SDK is present in 8.1 SDK doesn´t it? Anyway, I think this is not possible. Also, update your question.